# Inner helper with different conditions in foreach loop, how to manage that?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

Inner helper with different conditions in foreach loop, how to manage that?

I want to have different foreach loop, but the rest of the helper should be the same
Different version

```
   1 - foreach (var item in Model.Where(_ => _.Version > 0))
   2 - foreach (var item in Model.Where(_ => _.Version = 0))
   3 - foreach (var item in Model)
```

Any suggestions?

```
 @helper WriteGrid()
 {
  foreach (var item in Model.Where(_ => _.Version > 0))
  {
    <div>
     @item.From
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: What specifically are the different conditions? The three you put in the question would cause items with an ID of zero, or an ID of two, to be processed twice. Is that intentional, or is every item supposed to be processed at most once, or is every item supposed to be processed exactly once?

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer. Condition1 = Version1, Condition2 = All version expect Version1, Condition3 = ALL
More than once

Comment: What about making the loop body another helper?

Comment: Loop body with another helper is a solution

Comment: Why do you want to render the same item multiple time (the last loop duplicates those items that have already been rendered in the first two)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `@helper` a bit to take a [`Func<T,bool>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) which can decide which items to show:

```
@helper WriteGrid(Func<MyModel, bool> p)
{
    foreach (var item in Model.Where(p))
    {
        <div>@item.From</div>
    }
}

@WriteGrid(x => x.Version > 0)
<hr/>
@WriteGrid(x => x.Version == 0)
<hr/>
@WriteGrid(x => true)
<hr/>
```

Comment: I think your version is *far* more likely to be what the OP is after than mine, so I've deleted my answer. One change I'd make to simplify, though: I'd change `Predicate<MyModel>` to `Func<MyModel, bool>`, and pass it to `Where` directly.

Comment: Yes of course good point. I was just commenting that your answer is more efficient if they do want them directly after each other

Comment: yes they are both valid the updated version is just a bit cleaner